# R2D2 Tutorial, Using urdf with robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros, robot-state-publisher, urdf-tutorial, launch-file

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to follow the r2d2 tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher).  I ran

roscreate-pkg r2d2

I added dependencies to roscpp rospy std_msgs

and then I put the state_publisher.cpp file in r2d2/src.
I added rosbuild_add_executable(state_publisher state_publisher.cpp)

I added the launch file to the r2d2 directory as well.

When I try to run rosmake I get a fatal error:
'tf/transform_broadcaster.h' No such file or directory.

Although when I roscd to tf, I can find transform_broadcaster.cpp.

My questions are:

1. Do I have the r2d2 directory and files in the write places for how this tutorial should run or is there something I'm missing?
2. Why is it not finding tf/transform_broadcaster.h?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47618/r2d2-tutorial,-using-urdf-with-robot_state_publisher/) by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2012-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1.launch file should be added to r2d2/launch directory. But this is not relevant to the problem.

2.Because you didn't depend this package on "tf".You can solve this problem by adding the dependency to manifest.xml.

For example, your manifest.xml should looks like

```
<package>
  <description brief="r2d2_try">

     r2d2_try

  </description>
  <author>ROSfuerte</author>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="unreviewed" notes=""/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/r2d2_try</url>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>
  <depend package="rospy"/>
  <depend package="std_msgs"/>
  <depend package="tf"/>

</package>
```

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on 2012-11-07**:
Thanks, worked perfectly.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-07**:
Good~Then you should close this problem by marking this answer as correct so that this question won't track other attentions and we can concentrate on other unanswered questions: )

**Comment by [tangell](https://answers.ros.org/users/3534/tangell/) on 2012-11-07**:
I can't because my karma has to be at 25.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-07**:
Oh I mean pressing the check mark button in the left side of the answer zone instead of "closing" this question. This question might be helpful for other people in the future.